# Ошибка с com-портом на raspberry

Tags: linux, arduino, raspberry-pi, com-port

К Raspberry подключена Arduino, к ней датчик. Данные с него отправляются на com-порт 
Raspberry.
Когда хочу посмотреть, что там за шум, пишу

```
$ cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

Шума нет.

Запускаю *cutecom*, и шум в ней появляется.

Что мне надо сделать, чтобы шум шел без запуска *cutecom*?

---

P.S. После запуска *cutecom* и его последующего закрытия шум идет и в терминале.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. возможно, *cutecom* что-то записывает в файл терминального устройства: какую-нибудь «строку инициализации» или что-то подобное.

   надо вывести то же самое в файл:

   ```
   $ echo -n "..." | sudo tee -a /dev/ttyACM0
   ```
2. возможно, *cutecom* изменяет параметры терминального устройства: [управление потоком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) и тому подобное.

   надо установить такие же параметры с помощью, например, программы *stty*:

   ```
   $ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 ...
   ```

   подробнее — в `$ man stty`. узнать текущие параметры:

   ```
   $ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyACM0
   ```